# Differences between each F1-score values in sklearns.metrics.classification_report and sklearns.metrics.f1_score with a binary confusion matrix

Tags: python, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I have (true) boolean values and predicted boolean values like:

```
y_true = np.array([True, True, False, False, False, True, False, True, True,
       False, True, False, False, False, False, False, True, False,
        True, True, True, True, False, False, False, True, False,
        True, False, False, False, False, True, True, False, False,
       False, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False,
        True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, True, True, False, True, False, True, True, True,
       False, False, True, False, True, False, False, True, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False,
        True, True, True, True, False, False, True, False, True,
        True, False, True, False, True, False, False, True, True,
       False, False, True, True, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, True, True, False])

y_pred = np.array([False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, True,
       False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False,
       False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, True, False, False, False, False, True, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False,
       False, True, False, False, False, False, True, False, True,
        True, False, False, False, True, False, False, True, True,
       False, False, True, True, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, True, False, False])
```

I'm using the following imports

```
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score, classification_report, confusion_matrix
```

Confusion matrix looks like:

```
print(confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred))

[[67  0]
 [21 24]]
```

I'm doing:

```
print("f1_score: %f" % f1_score(y_true, y_pred))
print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred))
```

I get:

```
f1_score: 0.695652
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

      False       0.76      1.00      0.86        67
       True       1.00      0.53      0.70        45

avg / total       0.86      0.81      0.80       112
```

I see 4 values of `f1-score` (`0.695652`, `0.86`, `0.70`, `0.80`). I wonder what are differences between each values and how they are calculated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that `0.695652` is the same thing with `0.70`. In the scikit-learn `f1_score` [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html#sklearn.metrics.f1_score) explains that in default mode : F1 score gives the  `positive class` in binary classification.

Also you can easily reach the score of `0.86` with the formulation of F1 score. The formulation of F1 score is

```
F1 = 2 * (precision * recall) / (precision + recall)
```

**EDIT :**

Confusion matrix is something like that :

```
                    Prediction
                    FALSE | TRUE
True Value  FALSE    67      0
            TRUE     21      24

67 = True Negative, 0 = False Negative
21 = False Positive, 24  = True Positive
```

> In finding the avg / total, formula uses this values like you said in
>   the comment.

Comment: Ok thanks. I noticed that `f1_score(~y_true, ~y_pred) = 0.86451612903225816` but how to get 0.80 ? It seems to be `(45*f1_score(y_true, y_pred) + 67*f1_score(~y_true, ~y_pred)) / (67+45)`